# Why are long running SQL commands that return no data generating 100s of MBs of network traffic

Tags: c#, sql-server

Consider the contrived example below that I am executing against a remote server. The command itself returns no data but when I watch the process in Process Explorer I can see I am receiving tons of data over the network - with the example below I received ~370 MB. Watching Process Explorer on the DB Server I can see a network activity graph that perfectly matches the network activity graph on my client machine but this one for sent data.

What is causing this and how can I prevent it?

```
var query = @"
    declare @Value nvarchar(max), @index int
    set @index = 0

    while @index < 10000000
    begin
        set @Value = 'this is just a test'
        set @index = @index + 1
    end";

var connectionString = "MyConnectionString";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Hook up an event handler to the `SqlConnection.InfoMessage` event and see if you're getting spammed with events from the server.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The event never fires.

Comment: @JasonBoyd if you throw a `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in the query does the usage drop?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Simply adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first line does not seem to change anything. Am I misunderstanding you? Wrapping the entire thing up as a temp stored proc and setting nocount on the stored proc does eliminate the chatter though.

Answer (score 4):

SQL responds with a [DONE token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd340421.aspx) for each SQL statement in the batch. Each token is 13 bytes.

Each iteration of the loop represents 3 statements (2 set statements and the loop-conditional construct itself). 3 * 13 bytes * 10,000,000 = 390 MB.

You can avoid this by using [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql) (thanks, [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain)).

Comment: You just get [DONEINPROC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd340553.aspx) instead of DONE for stored procedures.

Comment: Oh, setting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in the query should fix the problem, that suppresses the DONE token and the DONEINPROC token.

Comment: I'm not sure this is _quite_ right, or I am doing something wrong. Simply adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` is not changing the behavior. Wrapping the entire thing up as a stored proc did not change the behavior either. But wrapping the entire thing up as a stored proc and adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the stored proc almost entirely eliminated the network traffic.